# Как сделать один запрос раз в час, другой раз в 24 часа

Tags: python, discord

Каким способом я могу сделать в скрипте, который работает безперерывно,один запрос раз в час, а другой раз в 24 часа.

```
def main():
    while True:
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_work)
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_daily)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Мне надо, чтобы запрос с msg_work выполнялся раз в час, а запрос с msg_daily раз в 24 часа. Я думал это реализовать как- то через time.sleep() но так и не придумал каким образом я могу это сделать

upd

Реализовал всё таки это через time.sleep()

```
def main():
    hours_passed = 0
    while True:
        if hours_passed == 0:  # a day has passed
            requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_daily)
            print(f'Daily success {datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}')
        requests.post(url, headers = auth, data = msg_work)
        print(f'Work success⛏ {datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}')
        hours_passed = (hours_passed + 1) % 24
        time.sleep(3600)  # it will sleep for a hour
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Но буду переделывать через `@tasks.loop()` так как выглядит более лаконично

Comment: Я рассматривал вариант сделать два отдельных скрипта, но он не очень подходит

Comment: Посмотрите еще commands.cooldown() https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого в discord py есть такая штука, как декоратор `@tasks.loop()`. Нужную вам асинхронную функцию вы должны обернуть в этот декоратор и указать с какой частотой эта функция будет выполняться. Например, пусть бот посылает сообщение в какой-то канал раз в сутки:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def write_a_message():
   await channel.send('Hello world!')
```

Время можно указывать не только в часах, но и в секундах и в минутах, для этого есть соответствующие параметры `minutes` и `seconds`. Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#api-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не прямо с точностью до секунды нужно каждый час и каждые сутки, то это возможно с помощью того же упомянутого вами модуля time.

Выполняем запрос с msg_work и сохраняем время, в которое он был выполнен. Выполняем запрос с msg_daily и сохраняем время, в которое он был выполнен. В бесконечном цикле при каждой итерации считываем время сейчас. Если оно больше на 3600 секунд (1 час), чем время последнего запроса msg_work, то снова выполняем запрос msg_work, если время сейчас больше на 86400 секунд (1 сутки), чем время запроса запроса msg_daily, то выполняем запрос msg_daily. Время считывается в формате UNIX, т.е. число прошедших секунд с 00:00:00 UTC 1 января 1970 года.

```
import time


requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=msg_work)
last_work_time = time.time()
requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=msg_daily)
last_daily_time = time.time()
while True:
    time_now = time.time()
    if time_now-last_work_time >= 3600: # прошло 3600 или больше секунд (1 час)
        requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=msg_work)
        last_work_time = time_now # меняем последнее время выполнения для msg_work
    elif time_now-last_daily_time >= 86400: # прошло 86400 или больше секунд (1 сутки)
        requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=msg_daily)
        last_daily_time = time_now # меняем последнее время выполнения для msg_daily
```

Comment: Это конечно сработает, но я бы советовал уменьшить частоту проверок, например, добавив `time.sleep()`. Так же, использование конструкции `if/elif` здесь неверно, так как события перехода в новый час и в новые сутки могут (и будут) происходить одновременно.

Comment: Это очень сложный способ, учитывая, что для данной задачи есть специальные методы

Comment: Насчёт добавить `time.sleep` согласен, но, исходя из того, что автор утверждает, что простой `time.sleep` на час и сутки ему не подойдёт, я подумал, что у автора в бесконечном цикле есть ещё код, который он не привел. А с какой периодичностью отсутсвующий код должен выполняться и сколько это займет времени, нам неизвестно. По поводу `if/ elif`: автор не упомянул о наличии многопоточности, поэтому я исходил из того, что её нет, следовательно два запроса одновременно выполняться не могут.